# Error 3146: ODBC--Call Failed with pass-through bulk insert

Tags: vba, ms-access, bulkinsert, pass-through

I am trying to do a Bulk Insert statement using a pass-through query. I have the following code:

```
sSQL = "BULK INSERT tbl_Name "
sSQL = sSQL & "FROM 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\File.txt' "
sSQL = sSQL & "WITH "
sSQL = sSQL & "("
sSQL = sSQL & "FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  "
sSQL = sSQL & "ROWTERMINATOR='\n'"
sSQL = sSQL & ");"

Set db = CurrentDb

    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")

        qdf.Connect = db.TableDefs("dbo_tbl_Name").Connect
        qdf.ReturnRecords = False
        qdf.SQL = sSQL
        qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

    Set qdf = Nothing

Set db = Nothing
```

The error I get is: `3146` with a description of `ODBC--call failed.`

If I change the sSQL statement to a INSERT STATEMENT or a SELECT statement, the query executes just fine.

Why does my BULK INSERT not work in the PASS through query? I print out my sSQL string to make sure it is correct, and it seems to be:

```
BULK INSERT tbl_Name FROM 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\File.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',', ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

Comment: On a side note: You can write that first piece of code as: `sSQL = "BULK INSERT tbl_Name & _` line break `more code here`. Or see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx

Comment: @Tom -- Thanks! I will definitely try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer to this problem. Apparently there is a time out setting for ODBC connections. By adding the code `qdf.ODBCTimeout = 900 '15 Min` the bulk insert was able to complete.

Thanks for everyone's time in this!